# Additional address storage in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to keep address of the last element of string, however my eax, ebx, ecx and edx are busy storing different data. Is there a way to store address of last element in different way or some different type of registry ?

Comment: How about `esi` or `esi`? Or store the value in memory. Or put one of the other registers on the stack temporarily so that you can use it to hold your new value.

Comment: There are also the SSE registers.

Comment: hmm, i see.. but can i increase adress of esi using    inc esi    to increase size of my string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in addition ESI, EDI, EBP registers;

Also you can store values in memory variables.

Also you can save some of the busy registers in the stack (`push` instruction), use them and then restore with `pop` instruction.

You should post some code in order to get more detailed answer.